# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ubosque.modelo.Ciudadano

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
No identifier specified for entity: com.ubosque.modelo.Ciudadano
```

my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ciudadano")
public class Ciudadano implements java.io.Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
@Column(name="fecha_nac")
private Date fechaNac;
@Column(name="lugar_nac")
private String lugarNac;
private String direccion;
private String telefono;
@Column(name="estado_civil")
private String estadoCivil;
private String email;
@Column(name="desc_perfil_prof")
private String descPerfilProf;

// setters & getters ...
```

I  know  this error  is  because  there is  no `@Id`  annotation,  but if I  add  `@Id` to  the id variable, when  I  deploy  this error  appears:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:
javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

and this  error  ONLY  disappears  when  I  remove the  `@Id`  annotation,  so  any suggestions  will be appreciated.

my project is made with `Maven 3`  and the dependencies donwloaded through `pom`  are:

1. mysql-connector-java-5.0.8
2. hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final

Comment: can you post your full stack trace? Also are you sure you have a column called ID in your table ciudadano that matches a numeric Integer type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception that you have (about Table.indexes) when you have an `@Id` present (which you must have, so really don't see the point in removing it) clearly has a cause exception that you don't post. More than likely it cannot find that annotation method (which is a JPA 2.1 method IIRC) since you have either a JPA implementation supporting JPA 2.0 and have a JPA2.1 jar in the CLASSPATH or vice-versa. Posting the cause exception would clarify which, and should have pointed you in the right direction