# Hibernate, No identifier specified for entity, For mapping String id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**I use :**

`mysql-connector-java 6.0.6`

`hibernate 5.2.10.Final`

`spring 4.3.8.RELEASE`

**Class code :**

```
public class PhoneNumber extends AbstractValue{

    public static final int CELL_PHONE = 1, HOME_PHONE = 2, WORK_PHONE = 3;

    public PhoneNumber(String value, Integer type) {
        super(value, type);
    }

    public PhoneNumber() {
        this(null,null);
    }

}
```

**Parent class :**

```
public abstract class AbstractValue {

    private String value;
    private Integer type;

    public AbstractValue(String value, Integer type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**Mapping :**

```
<entity class="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">
        <table name="PhoneNumber"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="value">
            </id>
            <basic name="type">
            <column nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

**Already tried :**

```
<entity class="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">
    <table name="PhoneNumber"/>
    <attributes>

        <id name="value" access="FIELD">
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="IdSeq" />
            <sequence-generator name="IdSeq" sequence-name="IdSeq" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="type">
            <column nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">
    <table name="PhoneNumber"/>
    <attributes>

        <id name="value">
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" generator="uuid" />
        </id>
        <basic name="type">
            <column nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">
    <table name="PhoneNumber"/>
    <attributes>

        <id name="value">
            <generated-value strategy="TABLE" generator="uuid" />
            <table-generator name="uuid" />
        </id>
        <basic name="type">
            <column nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

**And already read :** (so i hope i don't do duplicate)

[org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ubosque.modelo.Ciudadano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225440/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-com-ubosq)

[org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: login.Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442336/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-login-use)

[java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604927/java-lang-runtimeexception-org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-spe)

[Org.Hibernate.AnnotationException: No Identifier Specified For Entity I don't have a id in my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851029/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-i-dont-ha)

[org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity using JPA XML entity-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399934/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-using-jpa)

[No Identifier specified exception even when it was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320408/no-identifier-specified-exception-even-when-it-was)

[string id generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701105/string-id-generator)

[How to use @Id with String Type in JPA / Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate)

and some more...

**error :**

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.mayan.nst.server.model.PhoneNumber

IF its possible i was prefer a solution were the id will NOT be generated

Thanks you very mutch for read, and for any help

Comment: Is `AbstractValue` marked as an entity or mapped-superclass somewhere? Because it has the field you want to use identity and it isn't currently persistable with what you post there ...

Comment: Hey neil thank you for post here, i don't sure i understand you completely. the `PhoneNumber` is not abstract and the id is regular `String`.

Comment: The FIELD that you want to be the "id" is in `AbstractValue` CLASS. `AbstractValue` CLASS is NOT marked as "entity" or "mapped-superclass" so you cannot use fields in that class !! Solution is to mark `AbstractValue` as "mapped-superclass" ... like any JPA doc would tell you

Comment: neil  stocktin you right ! thank you very so much its work !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Neil Stocktin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380338/neil-stockton) the problem was that i tried to get superclass property from this child. (not working). solution will be add

```
<entity class="AbstractValue">
    <attributes>
        <id name="value">

        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

and remove the  from the child

**Update**

better solution, to separate the super class childrens tables. use :

```
<mapped-superclass class="AbstractValue">
    <attributes>
        <id name="value"/>
        <basic name="type">
            <column nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
```